# Magnitude of the faintest star visible to the human eye?

Tags: optics, astrophysics, astronomy, stars, telescopes

Hipparcus said the faintest magnitude of a star the human eye can see is 6.

How can one mathematically verify this?

So far:

Assumptions:

Human eye receives $1000 \,\mathrm{photons/(cm^2 \, Angstrom)}$

Human eye pupil area $=0.5 \,\mathrm{cm^2}$

Passband bandwitdh in the eye is $2000 \,\mathrm{Angstrom}$

integration time $=0.05 \,\mathrm{s}$

Calculations:

$n_\text{photons}=\text{flux}\times \text{area}\times \text{integration time}$

$\text{flux}=1000/{0.5\times 0.05}=40000 \text{photons/seconds Angstrom}$

How can I proceed from here?

Should i get data from a known star to use it to determine the magnitude?

Any hints or advice will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Hello! Please don't re-ask [closed questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/405887/apparent-magnitude-of-the-naked-eye).

Comment: I showed effort to work through the question and I asked if I should pursue a specific direction. And the answer, if given would have applied to several other problems and as this particular calculation has no easily find-able sources I believe it is in the best interest of the community to keep this question open. But your call...

Comment: @JDOe You might like to raise this issue in [chat].